# Apigee error "revision # does not exist" and can not delete

Tags: apigee

I have two end-points that are giving the following error when viewing the list of end-points:

> **Error while fetching Revision**
>
> APIProxy revision *[revision #]* does not exist for APIProxy *[end-point-name]* in organization *[org name]*

If I try to delete the end-point from the "Api Proxies" list I get the same message as above with the title of "**Error while deleting Api**"

If I go to the details for the end-point in question and select the revision mentioned from the drop down the page just spins the waiting symbol.

A co-worker started experiencing the same problem today as well and we would greatly like to be able to correct the situation and delete the bad revision.

Answer (score 0):

I would try deleting using the management API.

To delete a revision via API, you can use:

```
DELETE https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{orgName}/apis/{proxyName}/revisions/{revisionNum}
```

If that doesn't work, and you can delete the entire proxy (all revisions will be removed), you can use:

```
DELETE https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{orgName}/apis/{proxyName}
```

If you need to undeploy the proxy:

```
POST https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{orgName}/apis/{proxyName}/revisions/{revisionNum}/deployments?action=undeploy&env={environmentName}
```

or

```
DELETE https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{orgName}/env/{environmentName}/apis/{proxyName}/revisions/{revisionNum}/deployments
```

You can get the correct proxyName via:

```
GET https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{orgName}/apis
```

Please post the error you get if that doesn't work.

Comment: Here are the two messages I get back when trying to delete through the api

`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : "messaging.config.beans.ApplicationRevisionDoesNotExist",
  "message" : "APIProxy revision {revisionNum} does not exist for APIProxy {proxyName} in organization {orgName}",
  "contexts" : [ ]
}`

`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : "messaging.config.beans.ApplicationRevisionDoesNotExist",
  "message" : "APIProxy revision {revisionNum} does not exist for APIProxy {proxyName} in organization {orgName}",
  "contexts" : [ ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Chris -

This sounds like something that will require Apigee personnel to correct.

Would you please submit a ticket with Apigee Global Support?  Please reference the organization name, environment, API Proxy, and revision number in question.

Thanks.